# Securing objects in ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get security settings from the database for objects in a model. I would like to enable / disable / hide controls on my Rendered View depending upon the security settings for a user logged in.

This is what I have got so far:

```
public class RestrictedObjectsViewModel
{
    [SecureObject(ObjectId = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [SecureObject(ObjectId = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [SecureObject(ObjectId = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Using this approach, I would be querying the database for each object being rendered. Is it possible to query the database just once for the entire objects in the model to get a list of permissions for objects? How would I set that?

UPDATE:

Ok, let me go a bit into detail.

In my code when I set the following attribute to an object, i have programmed my HTML to hide the associated table row for the rendered object:

```
[SecureObject(IsInvisible = true)]
```

The above code works correctly in my tests. However, when i try to do the following:

```
public class RestrictedObjectsViewModel
{
    [SecureObject(IsInvisible = ObjectId3Invisible)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public RestrictedObjectsViewModel(bool setPermissions = false)
    {
        if (setPermissions)
        {
            ObjectId3Invisible = true;
        }
    }
    public bool ObjectId3Invisible = false;
}
```

I get an error message saying "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MyProject.Models.RestrictedObjectsViewModel.ObjectId3Invisible'"

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult RestrictedObjects()
{
    return View(new Models.RestrictedObjectsViewModel(true));
}
```

If i change the `ObjectId3Invisible` to static, i will not be able to change the value to true or false during runtime.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly query and store the metadata in a static context using the object's type as a reference? (Assuming all `ResrictedObjectsViewModel`s will have the same permissions applied.) Also, I assume `SecureObjectAttribute` is of your own creation?

Comment: Yes Brad, the SecureObject attribute is a custom attribute that I created myself. I am querying the database and getting the permissions for a logged in user for that object. I then store the object's permissions in its metadata. However, I am trying to minimize my trips to the database. For instance, if I have 20 objects on a page, I do not want to query the database 20 times. I would like to query it once for the entire ViewModel.

Comment: What defines what you classify as needing a single trip? Is it essentially one trip for `*ViewModel` or per `ObjectId` declaration?

Comment: I want a single trip for the entire ViewModel, and get permissions for each object in that view.